# How to click a button as same time a method is running in android

Tags: android, multithreading, text-to-speech

I have a method that running `TextToSpeech` and speech some text.and a button and a `EditText`.so i want if user put a number in `edittext` and click the button , currect text that is speeching stop and new one start based on user data in `edittext`.I used threads but it does not work.in this case if user click the button , the ui waits till speech finish , then do what i want.how can i do that?

Comment: Could you post what you have done?

Comment: Try using an AsyncTask. Some android operations require specification to run asynchronous to the ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

Code example taken from [Use Text-to-Speech on Android to Read Out Incoming Messages](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/use-text-to-speech-on-android-to-read-out-incoming-messages--cms-22524)

```
public void speak(String text){

    // Speak only if the TTS is ready
    // and the user has allowed speech

    if(ready && allowed) {
        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, 
                String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, hash);
    }
}
```

you can try queueMode [QUEUE_FLUSH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#QUEUE_FLUSH)